# What category is this? (Objects are sets and distinguished subsets of power set)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, category-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category whose

- objects are sets $X$ equipped with distinguished subsets of the associated power set $\mathcal{U}_X \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$, so that their union is all of $X$ (i.e. $\bigcup\limits_{U \in \mathcal{U}_X} U = X$).
- morphisms $(X, \mathcal{U}_X) \xrightarrow{f} (Y, \mathcal{U}_Y)$ are set functions $f: X \to Y$ so that for each element $V \in \mathcal{U}_Y$ the inverse image under $f$ is in $\mathcal{U}_X$ (i.e. $f^*: \mathcal{U}_Y \to \mathcal{U}_X$ is a function)

We know that the categories $Top$ of topological spaces and continuous functions as well as $Meas$ of sets with sigma algebras and measurable functions between them are full sub categories of this category.

**Is there a common name for $\mathcal{C}$?**

Comment: This, essentially, seems like a generalization of the category of elements of a functor (in this case, the contravariant power set functor) where you replace "elements" with "subobjects" (or, rather, the opposite category thereof because the functor is contravariant to begin with). But I don't know a general construction that specializes to this.

Comment: Thanks @Thorgott, yeah it's interesting. I'm also happy if people can suggest other contexts where this category holds a full subcategory useful to that context. Until further notice I'm just calling it ${\bf Set}_{Cov}$.

Comment: Is this not a "category of covers"? I made that u, but it looks like a reasonable word that may even be in use somewhere

Comment: If you remove the union condition, this is the category of "normal Chu spaces", see for example https://planetmath.org/chuspace

Answer (score 3):

Following your comment, let us call your category not $\mathcal{C}$, but $\mathbf{Set}_\mathrm{Cov}$, as it is slightly more descriptive. Let's place its construction in a more general theoretical context. There is an obvious forgetful functor $U\colon\mathbf{Set}_\mathrm{Cov}\to\mathbf{Set}$. This functor is a *Grothendieck fibration*, and your category $\mathbf{Set}_\mathrm{Cov}$ can be obtained via the [Grothendieck construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction).

Write $\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$ for the $(2,1)$-category of small $1$-categories. In short, there is for any category $\mathcal{D}$ a correspondence between $(2,1)$-functors $\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$ and so-called Grothendieck fibrations $p\colon\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is a $1$-category that may vary. A Grothendieck fibration $p\colon\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{D}$ is sent to a $(2,1)$-functor $\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$ that acts on objects essentially as $d\mapsto p^{-1}(d)$, and the definition on morphisms (and a proof of actual functoriality) uses the definition of a Grothendieck fibration. Conversely, there exists a *universal* Grothendieck **op**fibration $\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}_*\to\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$, and the Grothendieck fibration associated to a functor $(2,1)$-functor $F\colon\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$ is the $(2,1)$-pullback of this universal opfibration along $F^\mathrm{op}$.

This construction generalizes the category of elements of a functor in the following way. Embedding $\mathbf{Set}$ into $\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$ as the full $(2,1)$-subcategory of discrete categories, the above correspondence restricts to a correspondence between $1$-functors $\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ and a special kind of Grothendieck fibrations $\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{D}$, namely those with discrete fibers. For a functor $F\colon\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$, we call the domain $\mathcal{E}$ of the corresponding Grothendieck fibration $p\colon\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{D}$ the *category of elements* of $F$. One way to model it is as follows: the objects are pairs $(d,x)$, where $d\in\mathcal{D}$ and $x\in Fd$; a morphism from $(d,x)$ to $(d',x')$ is a morphism $f\colon d\to d'$ in $\mathcal{D}$ such that $Ff(x')=x$. One standard notation for this category is $\int F$.

In fact, for a general functor $F\colon\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$, the domain of the corresponding Grothendieck fibration into $\mathcal{D}$ is often written as $\int F$ as well. One can call $\int F$ the *Grothendieck construction of $F$*.

To obtain $\mathbf{Set}_\mathrm{Cov}$ as a Grothendieck construction, consider the functor $\mathrm{Cov}\colon\mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$, where $\mathrm{Cov}(X):=\{\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)\mid \bigcup\mathcal{U}=X\}$ is the **poset** (seen as a category) of all coverings of $X$, ordered by inclusion: there is an arrow $\mathcal{U}\to\mathcal{U}'$ iff $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathcal{U'}$, and if it exists, such an arrow is unique. A morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ induces a functor $f^*\colon\mathrm{Cov}(Y)\to\mathrm{Cov}(X)$ sending a covering $\mathcal{V}$ of $Y$ to the covering $\{f^{-1}(V)\mid V\in\mathcal{V}\}$ of $X$ (this preserves the inclusion order, so is a functor). Its corresponding Grothendieck fibration into $\mathcal{D}$ is equivalent to the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Set}_\mathrm{Cov}\to\mathbf{Set}$. Hence the category $\mathbf{Set}_\mathrm{Cov}$ can be safely called the Grothendieck construction of $\mathrm{Cov}$, and may also be written as $\int\mathrm{Cov}$.

By the way, there is a dual theory of Grothendieck opfibrations, which classify covariant $(2,1)$-functors into $\mathbf{Cat}^{(2,1)}$, rather than contravariant ones. The universal Grothendieck opfibration with discrete fibers is the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Set}_*\to\mathbf{Set}$ from pointed to unpointed sets, and $\mathbf{Set}_*$ is accordingly the category of elements (but now the covariant version) of the identity functor $\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$. This explains why general categories of elements and their forgetful functors actually model all Grothendieck (op)fibrations with discrete fibers.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, thank you for taking the time. I’m giving it 1-2 more days to see if anyone has anything else to add but I’m convinced this is right.